# Empty pyramid in python 3

Tags: python

I want to print an empty pyramid in python 3 and my teacher suggested me this code but i am confused about the list(array) and i want an alternative of this code. Is there any alternative method to print an empty pyramid. This code is also available on available on stackoverflow but i want to solve it by using simple if else.

```
#Function Definition
def Empty_triangle(n): # Here value of n is 5
    for i in list(range(n-1))+[0]:

        line = ""
        leadingSpaces = n-2-i       

        line += " "*leadingSpaces  
        line += "*"
        if i != 0:
            middleSpaces = 2*i-1
            line += " "*middleSpaces
            line += "*"
        print(line)


# Function Call
n = 5             
Empty_triangle(n)
```

---

Example of code which i want
if (row==0 and row==5 and col!=0):

output should like this using ifelse

[Can it be done with simple if else](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbd5p.png)

Comment: What should the output look like?

Comment: wait i post an image of output

Comment: All respectable members can i do it using simple if else statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code your teacher suggested, the "list" seems redundant.   When n=5, the "`range(n-1)`" command already gives you the numeric list `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`.  Since it's already a list, you don't need to put "list()" around it.  Then the "+[0]" just adds 0 to the end to give you `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0]`.  Also, I'm not sure if you want that extra star at the bottom center.

There are lots of alternative ways to do it, but here's an alternative version I made:

```
def triangle2(n):
    for row in range(n):
        line = [ ' ' for i in range(n+row+1)]
        line[n-row] = '*'
        line[n+row] = '*'
        print ''.join(line)

triangle2(5)
```

For each row, it creates a list of spaces that's just big enough for that row, then it replaces the spaces with the locations of where the stars should be.  Finally it joins all of the spaces and stars into a string, and prints it.

An even shorter way is to essentially take half of each row, then mirror it to make the second half:

```
def triangle3(n):
    for row in range(n):
        line = [ ' ' for i in range(n-row) ] + ['*'] + [ ' ' for i in range(row)]
        print(''.join(line[:-1] + line[::-1]))
```

Or skipping lists and joins and just using concatenated strings:

```
def triangle4(n):
    for row in range(n):
        first_half = ' '*(n-row) + '*' +  ' '*row
        second_half =  first_half[::-1][1:]
        print(first_half + second_half)
```

The "`[::-1]`" part is a little trick to reverse a string or list.

Comment: `triangle4` looks nicest to me

Answer (score -1):

```
# Python 3.x code to demonstrate star pattern 

# Function to demonstrate printing pattern triangle 
def triangle(n): 

  # number of spaces 
  k = 2*n - 2

  # outer loop to handle number of rows 
  for i in range(0, n): 

    # inner loop to handle number spaces 
    # values changing acc. to requirement 
    for j in range(0, k): 
        print(end=" ") 

    # decrementing k after each loop 
    k = k - 1

    # inner loop to handle number of columns 
    # values changing acc. to outer loop 
    for j in range(0, i+1): 

        # printing stars 
        print("* ", end="") 

    # ending line after each row 
    print("\r") 

 # Driver Code 
 n = 5
 triangle(n)
```

careful with indent.
previously whole code wasn't displayed.

Comment: which code please can you tell me about which code you are talking about. I can see here my all codes.

Comment: I tried to run it in python 3 but it is still showing error (unindent does not match any outer indentation level) in the last in n=5